# public function find_ID($post_ID = false)

Tags: codeigniter

Can someone explain this code:

Why $post_ID = false being written in the codes:

models/post_model.php

```
 public function find_ID($post_ID = false)
{
}
```

views/0headers.php

```
$article = $this->post_model->find_ID(48);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't understand why it is in a function inside a model. The code inside that function may explain that.
It means if no `$post_ID` is passed from controller then take `$post_ID` as `false` to use it somewhere inside the function.

Example call would look like this:

```
$article = $this->post_model->find_ID();
```

Comment: What false means?  Is it a boolean value?

Comment: Is stating : $post_ID = false 

means to cancel - 48 

$article = $this->post_model->find_ID(48);

Comment: No. Please have a look at my answer again. "if no $post_ID is passed from controller " false will be assigned to $post_ID.

Comment: Then, if it has a value then it start using the variable.

Comment: Yes. It it has content(eg: 48), $post_ID will contain that instead of false.